# Javascript error "Cannot set property 'value' of null'

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<body onload="UserAction()">


<form action="student" id="add" align="center">
    Rollno:<input type="text" name="rollNo"  id="rollNo"><br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <br>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function UserAction() {

            var rollNo = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("rollNo"));
            document.write(rollNo);
            document.getElementById("rollNo").value = rollNo;
        }
</script>
```

The `rollNo` value gets printed but while assigning it to the textbox it gives me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have replaced the entire HTML from the page when you do

`document.write(rollNo);`

If your `rollNo` is say, `10` then you will get

```
<body>10</body>
```

rendered in the browser when your `UserAction()` function is invoked. So you need to remove this line `document.write(rollNo);` so that the next line `document.getElementById("rollNo")` can find the element with `id` as `rollNo`. So you `UserAction()` becomes,

```js
function UserAction() {
  //get roll no from localstorage
  var rollNo = 10;
  document.getElementById("rollNo").value = rollNo;
}
```

```html
<body onload="UserAction()">


  <form action="student" id="add" align="center">
    Rollno:<input type="text" name="rollNo" id="rollNo"><br> Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <br>
  </form>

</body>
```

And in this way when the element is detected by `document.getElementById("rollNo")` you will not get the error `"Cannot set property 'value' of null'`

Comment: thanks it worked actually i wrote document.write() to test the content of the variable,henceforth i will ignore it

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the function with the following lines:

```
function UserAction() {
        var rollNo = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("rollNo"));
        document.getElementById("rollNo").value= rollNo;
    }
```

The mistake you're committing is replacing the entire body with roll number instead of that particular input field.

As the entire body is replaced with the rollnumber in localstorage, there is no element with id 'rollNo', hence the error says that it cannot set property 'value' of null.